# Turning scripts off and on based on Media Queries?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, enquire.js

I am using a widget in my layout and I have it now so when a certain breakpoint is hit it will not display that larger widget and then goes to the smaller one.  The larger widget does hide and the smaller one shows up but the text that is associated with both isn't right.

The text for the large widget displays and the smaller text for the small widget doesn't.  I am pretty sure it has to do with the scripts each are using.  The display none does hide the elements but the scripts seem to be still running.

I have absolutely no clue about JavaScript yet and would prefer a HTML or CSS answer if possible.  If not then I will go with JS but will need some direction please.  I have read numerous articles and even in the process of learning JS but still not sure how some of what I've read applies.

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  // styles
}

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
  // scripts
}
```

This is what I've found that seems like it is what I need but I'm not sure on the syntax of how to call the script I need.  Do I just put the script itself in there without any other information?  I have also read about using jquery to do this with something like this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(this).width() > 480) {
  // call supersize method
}
});
```

And I've even read about using Modernizer to do this but I still have to go through the documentation.

In the bin it doesn't show any of the text at all but the larger text is there and off to the side of the small widget.  I just need to shut that large script off and turn the other on at a certain media query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
  <aside class="smallScreen">
      <div class="smallWeather" style='width: 200px; height: 440px; background-image:
  url(http://vortex.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/backgrounds/red_500x440_bg.jpg
  ); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #993333;' ><div 
  id='NetweatherContainer' style='height: 420px;' ><script src='http://...'></script>  
  </div></div></aside>
  </div></div></div></aside>


  <aside class="largeScreen">
      <div class="largeWeather" style='width: 500px; height: 440px; background-image:
  url(http://vortex.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/backgrounds/red_500x440_bg.jpg
  ); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #993333;' ><div 
  id='NetweatherContainer' style='height: 420px;' ><script src='http://...'></script>  
  </div></div></aside>
```

CSS

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 564px) and (max-width: 604px) {
  .largeScreen {
display: none;
}

  .smallScreen {
display: block; 
width: 55%;
min-width: 240px;
height: 100%;
font-size: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

  .smallWeather {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 240px;
height: 420px;  
background: white;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

What is the best way to do this and why please?  Is jQuery the best way from a mobile performance standpoint?

**UPDATE**:  Going to use [enquire.js](http://jsbin.com/OvELamU/1/edit?html,js,output) because of it's straightforward approach (although I'm still a bit sketchy on it's use) and how small it is.

This is the basic code:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 605px)", {

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when a media query matches.
match : function() {},      

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions 
// *from a matched state to an unmatched state*.
unmatch : function() {},    

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered once, when the handler is registered.
setup : function() {},    

// OPTIONAL, defaults to false
// If set to true, defers execution of the setup function 
// until the first time the media query is matched
deferSetup : true,

// OPTIONAL
// If supplied, triggered when handler is unregistered. 
// Place cleanup code here
destroy : function() {}

});
```

Still not done and looking for more support with this.  Now that I've chose this route, I see that there is quite a few articles and questions already about enquire.js.  I will update my situation as I read up.

**UPDATE**:  This is where I'm at but it's not working yet.  I have the styles associated with each script still in the HTML and display none used accordingly.  Will doing this work once I get the enquire.js correct?

Here is the new [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OvELamU/1/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks again for everything!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), which is a lightweight JavaScript library for responding to CSS media queries.

If you don't want to use a library, [this post on reacting to media queries in JavaScript](http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript) runs through a way of doing what you are after with vanilla JavaScript.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/dULKh/1/)</kbd> with some working example code, and here's a <kbd>[**Fullscreen jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/dULKh/1/embedded/result/)</kbd>, which is handy when trying to test how it works. If you use the fullscreen version and make the browser window less than `600px` wide, a javascript alert will tell you that you have done so. Because the alert comes up, the browser will jump back to its original size and tell you that it got bigger than `600px` again. So you can see, it calls the match function when it matches (so at the time of loading and at the time of resizing to a larger width), and it calls the unmatch function when resizing to a smaller width, because then the media query doesn't match any more. That's how you call a certain function only for mobile or only for desktop based on their screen size.

**JS**

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width:600px)", {
    match: function () {
        alert("Now the screen width is more than 600px");
    },
    unmatch: function () {
        alert("Now the screen width is less than 600px");
    }
});
```

Comment: OK so I have narrowed my focus down to enquire.js and using a jQuery approach but think maybe enquire is the way to go.  I will try to come up with something and post back shortly.

Comment: One other thing I would ask is if I already have modernizer in place then would it infact be better to use that then enquire.js?

Comment: @InfinityDesigns - [You should have a look here](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#legacy-browsers), it explains how to use *Modernizr* and *enquire.js* together. Just providing a basic rundown in this comment, you should look at it this way: *enquire.js* relies on the `matchMedia` API, this API is not universally available in all browsers. Now for *enquire.js* to work in all browsers, you should use *Modernizr* to detect if the `matchMedia` API is supported in the current browser, if not, use *Modernizr* to load a *polyfill* which adds support for the `matchMedia` API to the current browser.

Comment: @InfinityDesigns - The point of the story above, is to make it clear that *Modernizr* doesn't in any way replace *enquire.js*, simply because it does not provide the functionality *enquire.js* provides. But *enquire.js* should be used together with *Modernizr* to ensure that *enquire.js's* functionality is supported and keeps working in older browsers. For technical details on how to make them work together, [you should read up at the link I provided in my previous comment](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#legacy-browsers).

Comment: OK now I'm starting to understand.  Thank you so much Mathijs, learning bits and pieces of Javascript and these other libraries has proven to be a challenge for me so far.

Comment: Still looking for help with this, please.  I have went through 4 different fiddle examples and still do not understand what I need to do.  I have put quite a bit into this and still do not understand.

Comment: Dang, went over 5 minutes editing.  Still looking for help with this, please.  I have went through 4 different fiddle examples and countless articles and examples from the author (Nick Williams/Wicky Nilliams) and still do not understand what I need to do.  When using the match and unmatch function, how do you call a script for mobile and one for desktop.  Please give an actual script example, I have seen for responsive image replacement, different variables and whatnot added but nothing with script examples.

Comment: Still looking for help on this.  I will be putting more time towards learning JS down the road a bit but for now I could really use some help, thanks!

Comment: I've updated my post again with the example I have but still notta.  Any other help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks